# How to debug a shared library using GDB?

Tags: gdb, shared-libraries

I want to debug a **SharedLib** which is called by **Main**. I have the sources of the SharedLib and of Main. I compile and link Main and SharedLib with the option **–g3**. The variables **PATH** and **LD_LIBRARY_PATH** include **/PathToSharedLib**. I set a breakpoint in b **FileOfSharedLib.c** at **NNN**.

```
(gdb) file /PathToMain/Main
Reading symbols from /PathToMain/Main...done.
(gdb) set directories /PathToSourceOfSharedLib
(gdb) set solib-search-path /PathToSharedLib
(gdb) sharedlibrary SharedLib
No loaded shared libraries match the pattern `SharedLib`
(gdb) b FileOfSharedLib.c:NNN
No source file named FileOfSharedLib.c.
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]) y
(gdb) run
```

It never stops at the break point which is called several times by Main. I see it by printf statements in the log of the SharedLib. It looks like that the SharedLib is not considered by gdb.

I checked the SharedLib and the FileOfSharedLib.c:

```
(gdb) file /PathToSharedLib/SharedLib
Reading symbols from /PathToSharedLib/SharedLibl...done.
(gdb) b FileOfSharedLib.c:123
Breakpoint 1 at 0x43d7f: file FileOfSharedLib.c, line 123.
(gdb)
```

I am running Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-66-generic i686) with gcc 4.8.4 and gdb 7.7.1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> It never stops at the break point which is called several times by Main.

This implies a bug in GDB. Unfortunately your version of GDB is too old for developers to care. Try reproducing this behavior with current GDB 7.11.1, and file a bug in GDB [bugzilla](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/enter_bug.cgi?product=gdb) if it does reproduce.

If you don't want to use GDB 7.11.1, you can work around this bug by setting a breakpoint *after* the shared library has been loaded.

If the library is linked into the main executable directly, the following sequence should work:

```
(gdb) start
# GDB stop on entry to main

(gdb) b FileOfSharedLib.c:NNN  # should find the source now
```

If the library is `dlopen`ed, you'll need to set a temporary breakpoint in the main exectable somewhere after that `dlopen`.

Another workaround: `set stop-on-solib-events 1`. This will make GDB stop after any new shared library is added (or removed).

Comment: For others finding this answer: gdb successfully set a breakpoint this way for me, but still ran until completion without stopping at the breakpoint, even though logs indicated that the function executed. The problem was that it was executed in a child process. You can use follow-fork-mode or detach-on-fork to set gdb's handling of child processes.